# Unity Steam VR launches incorrect

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive, steamvr

I've programmed a virtual reality game for the HTC Vive in Unity. I used Steam VR.
If I play the game on Unity, everything runs perfectly. It runs also perfectly if I build it. But if I copy my build to another computer, nothing's working. 
It looks like this:[top right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spiUu.png)

Does anyone no how to solve this?.
My Vive is setup correctly and other games are working just fine.

Thank you
Roman

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure before each build that OpenVR is set as first target in the player settings and not "None" (sometimes Unity changes it).
2. On the other computers, they should obviously have Steam and SteamVR installed
3. Since Steam workflow is to launch games from Steam Library,which launch SteamVR automaticly. make sure the SteamVR app is launched before launching your .exe.